# What specs of power supply are needed for a Terminator 2 console?

Tags: technical-issues, terminator-2

I recently dug up my decades old Terminator 2 video console (aka Ending-Man BS-500 AS), and, because of nostalgia, I wanted to play some Mario on it. Unfortunately, I'm missing the power supply cable and I have no clue on what its power supply requirements are.

Comment: Sometimes consoles and other hardware (like laptops) will have the power specifications etched into the plastic or printed on a sticker on the bottom. Is there anything like that on the console itself?

Comment: Unfortunately no... I've also opened up the console to see if these details are written somewhere inside it, but still nothing...

Answer (score -1):

Either a 9 Volt Adapter or 12 Volt Adapter should work. Both should work on the 9 Volt Adapter. I have the same console/game and it works. Do not use an adapter that is higher than 12 Volt.

Comment: You should add more detail, saying why it is 9v.

Answer (score -1):

Output : 9V
Max current : 500ma
Power : 4W

Comment: I think this answer could be improved a lot if you mentioned where you got these numbers from.

Comment: Not to mention that 9V at 500mA gives a max power of 4.5W...